# Windows Boot Manager first screen is in English, it should be in Italian

Tags: windows-7, language, bootmgr

Yesterday I installed openSUSE 11.4 on my Windows 7 machine.

Despite my indication of installing grub on the openSUSE root partition, it has been installed on MBR, overwriting Windows Boot Manager. So I entered Windows Recovery, and asked it to fix my boot problems. Windows Boot Manager is now back and working correctly, but the first screen (the one with the OS selection, and with "Press TAB to change menu" and Windows Memory Diagnostic, is in English instead of Italian.

I  tried `bcdedit /set locale it-IT` and `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} locale it-IT` with no avail. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bcdboot c:\windows /l it-it` did the trick.